# Rewrite of an vanilla JS Pong with the help of PixiJS

Tags: javascript, pixi.js

I tried to rewrite a vanilla JavaScript Pong game in addition with PixiJS, mainly because I had resizing issues to get the canvas responsive.

The resizing works fine with PixiJS, but all the objects started to have trailing paths: [Fiddle1](https://jsfiddle.net/02utycqq)

I figured that's because added new instances on update instead of just updating the position, so I tried to rework it from scratch again. The movement of the player works so far but I can't manage to get the ball working...I am kinda lost and willed to learn. Help is much appreciated ...Thanks a lot!

[Fiddle2](https://jsfiddle.net/hendrikeng/02utycqq/3)

```
import 'pixi.js';

// define gamne variables
const appWidth = window.innerWidth;
const appHeight = window.innerHeight;
const paddleWidth = 150;
const paddleHeight = 30;
const ballSize = 15;
const halfBall = ballSize / 2;
const appWidthHalf = appWidth / 2;
const appHeightHalf = appHeight / 2;
const paddleWidthHalf = paddleWidth / 2;
const pongColor = 0x57dfbf;
const bgColor = 0x282625;
const computerPositionX = appWidthHalf - paddleWidthHalf;
const computerPositionY = 50;
const playerPositionX = computerPositionX;
const playerPositionY = appHeight - computerPositionY - paddleHeight;
const ballPositionX = appWidthHalf - halfBall;
const ballPositionY = appHeightHalf - halfBall;
const playerSpeed = 4;
const computerSpeed = 4;
const ballSpeed = 3;

// Setup the ticker and the root stage PIXI.Container.
const app = new PIXI.Application(appWidth, appHeight, {
  antialias: false,
  backgroundColor: bgColor,
  transparent: false,
  resolution: 1,
});

// append app to body
document.body.appendChild(app.view);

// create graphic elements
const player = new PIXI.Graphics();
const computer = new PIXI.Graphics();
const ball = new PIXI.Graphics();

// Player
player
  .beginFill(pongColor)
  .drawRect(playerPositionX, playerPositionY, paddleWidth, paddleHeight)
  .endFill();

// Computer
computer
  .beginFill(pongColor)
  .drawRect(computerPositionX, computerPositionY, paddleWidth, paddleHeight)
  .endFill();

// Ball
ball
  .beginFill(pongColor)
  .drawRect(ballPositionX, ballPositionY, ballSize, ballSize)
  .endFill();

// Player Movement
player.update = function () {
  for (const key in keysDown) {
    const value = Number(key);
    if (value === 37) {
      player.move(-playerSpeed, 0);
    } else if (value === 39) {
      player.move(playerSpeed, 0);
    } else {
      player.move(0, 0);
    }
  }
};

player.move = function (x, y) {
  this.x += x;
  this.y += y;
  this.x_speed = x;
  this.y_speed = y;
  if (this.x < -appWidthHalf + paddleWidthHalf) {
    this.x = -appWidthHalf + paddleWidthHalf;
    this.x_speed = 0;
  } else if (this.x + this.width - paddleWidthHalf > appWidthHalf) {
    this.x = appWidthHalf - this.width + paddleWidthHalf;
    this.x_speed = 0;
  }
};

// computer Movement
// eslint-disable-next-line
computer.update = function(ball) {
  const x_pos = ball.x;
  let diff = -(computer.x + paddleWidthHalf - x_pos);
  if (diff < 0 && diff < -computerSpeed) {
    diff = -ballSize;
  } else if (diff > 0 && diff > computerSpeed) {
    diff = ballSize;
  }
  computer.position.set(diff, 0);
  if (computer.x < 0) {
    computer.x = 0;
  } else if (computer.x + paddleWidthHalf > appWidth) {
    computer.x = appWidth - paddleWidthHalf;
  }
};

// Ball Movement
ball.update = function (paddle1, paddle2) {
  this.x += this.x_speed;
  this.y += this.y_speed;
  const top_x = this.x - ballSize;
  const top_y = this.y - ballSize;
  const bottom_x = this.x + ballSize;
  const bottom_y = this.y + ballSize;
  if (this.x - ballSize < 0) {
    this.x = ballSize;
    this.x_speed = -this.x_speed;
  } else if (this.x + ballSize > appWidth) {
    this.x = appWidth - ballSize;
    this.x_speed = -this.x_speed;
  }

  if (this.y < 0 || this.y > appHeight) {
    this.x_speed = 0;
    this.y_speed = ballSpeed;
    this.x = appWidthHalf;
    this.y = appHeightHalf;
  }

  if (top_y > appHeightHalf) {
    if (
      top_y < paddle1.y + paddle1.height &&
      bottom_y > paddle1.y &&
      top_x < paddle1.x + paddle1.width &&
      bottom_x > paddle1.x
    ) {
      this.y_speed = -ballSpeed;
      this.x_speed += paddle1.x_speed / 2;
      this.y += this.y_speed;
    }
  } else if (
    top_y < paddle2.y + paddle2.height &&
    bottom_y > paddle2.y &&
    top_x < paddle2.x + paddle2.width &&
    bottom_x > paddle2.x
  ) {
    this.y_speed = ballSpeed;
    this.x_speed += paddle2.x_speed / 2;
    this.y += this.y_speed;
  }
};

// controls
const keysDown = {};

window.addEventListener('keydown', (event) => {
  keysDown[event.keyCode] = true;
});

window.addEventListener('keyup', (event) => {
  delete keysDown[event.keyCode];
});

// update function
function update() {
  player.update();
  computer.update(ball);
  ball.update(player, computer);
}

// append childs to app
app.stage.addChild(player);
app.stage.addChild(computer);
app.stage.addChild(ball);

// game loop
app.ticker.add(update);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fiddle 1 definitely had issue, as you were not changing the ball.x and y there, but instead changing the graphics object, in fiddle2 it seemed, you were doing 
good job with it. You just have some logical errors in the code, regarding setting the x- and y-coordinates and the ball movement.

So if you add console.log(this.x, this.y) inside the ball.update function in fiddle2, you will notice the NaN values.

To see the ball moving, if you set the initial values with:

```
ball.x_speed = 0;
ball.y_speed = 0;
```

And then

```
paddle.x_speed
paddle.y_speed
```

To

```
paddle.x
paddle.y
```

You see the ball moving at least (though collision logic doesn't work), (modified example in the fiddle below)
https://jsfiddle.net/4L6zbd01/